# SpringBoot - NumberFormatException on "favicon.ico"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I just built a SpringBoot Application that seems to work, but it stop a few hours after. When I checked the logs, I just saw the following warning (multiple times):

```
2021-06-28 09:54:37.704  WARN 25077 --- [nio-8894-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "favicon.ico"]
```

There is no occurence of Long.parseLong() or "favicon.ico" in my application.

Does someone had any similar problem ?

Comment: This is a *warning*, it won't stop your app. Check your logs for ERROR.

Comment: Please add further logs as well.

Comment: Please add more logs and your code snippet.